# How to go about building an iPhone app that accesses a website with a custom UI?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I don't quite know how to explain this but I want to build an app that can access a website like, for example, Facebook, but I don't actually want it to be Facebook's website in the sense that I want to design the UI. There is a couple of apps like this already in the app store, one being called "Facebook Touch HD". I have managed to get an app to access Facebook with UIWebView, but it just goes to Facebook's mobile website, obviously.

Comment: is facebook just an example or the exact website you're trying to use?

Comment: Maybe, but I haven't really decided yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to fetch data from Facebook using its APIs. Facebook actually offers a [library for iOS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/), so you may want to check it out.

In general, this applies to any site that offers an API. Usually you can use `NSURLConnection` to make requests to get the data you're interested in (check the specific API's documentation for details); then you have parse that data (most services output data in XML or JSON).

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Facebook IOS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/).